# Probability regarding balls and urns, uneven distribution

Tags: probability

I'm sure there must be a problem like this posted already, apologize for the duplicate- all the names are so similar I can't find one sifting through. The problem goes like this:

Urn 1 contains 3 white balls and one red ball. Urn 2 contains 2 white balls and 3 red balls.

a) An urn is chosen at random, and a ball is drawn from it at random. If the ball drawn is R, what is the probability the urn now contains no red balls?

answer: .25, which I'm pretty confident is right. Feel free to correct me.

This is the part where I'm stuck.

b) An urn is is chosen at random which will *give* a ball, and the other one will *receive* that ball. Then, a ball is drawn at random from the urn the received a ball. Given that this ball drawn is red, what is the probability that the donating urn now contains no red balls?

It seems like this should also just be $\frac13$, since there are only 3 balls that can be drawn initially resulting in in an urn with 0 reds; the 2 whites drawn from urn 2, or the red drawn from urn 1. Is this correct?

Comment: A quick calculation gives me a different number than yours on the first problem. Note that in the current post, there are $2$ white and $3$ red in the second urn. We can use informal reasoning, or a formal conditional probability calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that choosing an urn at random means choosing each with probability $\frac12$, the probability of drawing a red ball from Urn $1$ is $\frac12\cdot\frac14=\frac18$. The probability of drawing a red ball from Urn $2$ is $\frac12\cdot\frac35=\frac3{10}$. Given that you’ve drawn a red ball, the probability that it came from Urn $1$ is therefore
$$\frac{\frac18}{\frac18+\frac3{10}}=\frac{\frac18}{\frac{17}{40}}=\frac5{17}\;,$$ not $\frac14$.

For (b), look at the possible sequences of events.

- You draw the first ball from Urn $1$, it’s red, and then you draw a red ball from Urn $2$: the probability of this is $\frac12\cdot\frac14t\cdot\frac23$. (Why?)
- You draw the first ball from Urn $1$, it’s white, and then you draw a red ball from Urn $2$: the probability of this is $\frac12\cdot\frac34\cdot\frac12$. (Why?)
- You draw the first ball from Urn $2$, it’s red, and then you draw a red ball from Urn $1$; what’s the probability of this?
- You draw the first ball from Urn $2$, it’s white, and then you draw a red ball from Urn $1$; what’s the probability of this?

The sum of these four probabilities is the probability of drawing a red ball the second time. What fraction of this probability comes from cases that leave the donating urn without red balls?

Comment: for part 1, I thought that was how it worked, but I was specifically corrected to the way I did it earlier in the year. Are you sure?

Comment: @Nick: Yes, assuming that my interpretation of the problem is correct. What calculations/reasoning did you use to get $\frac14$?

Comment: There are 4 red balls in total. The selection of an urn at random is inconsequential; it's just 1 of the 4 red balls. that's how I got to 1/4.

Comment: @Nick: But the $4$ red balls aren’t equally likely to be chosen. The probability of choosing any specific ball in Urn $1$ is the probability of choosing Urn $1$ and then of choosing that ball, or $\frac12\cdot\frac14=\frac18$. The probability of choosing any specific ball in Urn $2$ is similarly $\frac12\cdot\frac15=\frac1{10}$.

Comment: so if the jars had an equal number of balls in them (which was the case in the other problem), then that would be how you do it?

Comment: @Nick: Yes, because then the balls would all be drawn with equal probability. You should try an example or two, though, to convince yourself that in that case both methods yield the same result.

Comment: one last question, in your first section of part b, you said (1/2)(1/8)(2/3). Should that 1/8 be 1/4? I don't see why it would be 1/8, the other 2 parts make sense.

Comment: @Nick: Yes, that was a typo, or maybe I unconsciously did the first multiplication mentally and typed the product. (Sorry to be so slow; I’ve been off-line.)